# Fallout Terminal Hacking

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Anyone here a die-hard Bethesda fan? Maybe you prefer Obsidian Entertainment? Well, if you're either of those things than the following picture should be relatively familiar to you.

[image: The fallout terminal.]

I've taken the liberty of preparing a rather unique ASCII-Art challenge, so here's the first clue as to what I'm going to have you do:

```
  _____________________________________________________
 /                                                     \ 
|     _____________________________________________     |
|    |                                             |    |
|    | Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   |    |
|    | Password Required                           |    |
|    | Attempts Remaining:                         |    |
|    |                                             |    |
|    | 0x01                 | 0x0D                 |    |
|    | 0x02                 | 0x0E                 |    |
|    | 0x03                 | 0x0F                 |    |
|    | 0x04                 | 0x10                 |    |
|    | 0x05                 | 0x11                 |    |
|    | 0x06                 | 0x12                 |    |
|    | 0x07                 | 0x13                 |    |
|    | 0x08                 | 0x14                 |    |
|    | 0x09                 | 0x15                 |    |
|    | 0x0A                 | 0x16                 |    |
|    | 0x0B                 | 0x17                 |    |
|    | 0x0C                 | 0x18                 |    |
|    |_____________________________________________|    |
|                                                       |
\_______________________________________________________/ 
       \_______________________________________/
```

This is a very basic (blank) template for the RobCo Fallout terminal design in pure ASCII, your job will be to:

- First, generate this template.
- Then, given a list of strings `l` and a number `0 <= n <= 4` to fill it up!

The two dynamic parts of a fallout hacking terminal are:

## The Number of Attempts

- The number of attempts you have remaining (indicated by space delimited boxes.

  - For the purpose of this challenge you will be using `X` instead of `■`.

## The Passwords

- The passwords, defined by `l`, are interspersed with random printable ASCII symbols.
- The passwords, as you can tell by the example, can wrap multiple rows (`NAMES`).
- All passwords in the terminal screen should have an equal chance of being anywhere.
- All passwords can be expected to be of equal length, though this doesn't matter.
- The list of symbols usable to separate passwords are: `!"#$%&'()*+/:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}`.
- All passwords in `l` must be of equal length.
- PASSWORDS MUST HAVE THE POTENTIAL TO WRAP BETWEEN BOTH COLUMNS.

  - This also goes for rows, but only to a higher byte address (0x18->0x01 is invalid).
- The display space for passwords on either side is 15 wide (with a space on either side).

  - You may assume no words in `l` will be longer than this.
- Passwords are alphabetical only, meaning only letters.

---

Example:

`l = ["SMART","ENACT","SWORE","PITYS","SMELL","CARTS","RACES"]`, `n = 4`

```
  _____________________________________________________
 /                                                     \ 
|     _____________________________________________     |
|    |                                             |    |
|    | Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   |    |
|    | Password Required                           |    |
|    | Attempts Remaining: X X X X                 |    | # N = 4 drives these X's.
|    |                                             |    |
|    | 0x01 $?_/%$ENACT||"} | 0x0D TYS"_'$\#|^%&{} |    |
|    | 0x02 }:!*@{/_<"[]#>; | 0x0E #{!"^&\]'|}_[$% |    |
|    | 0x03 $%&'()*+/:;<\_' | 0x0F }|[(%SMELL/_$@( |    |
|    | 0x04 ^SMART(!@$*'^_@ | 0x10 []_#!"{|}'%$\&^ |    |
|    | 0x05 (*@#%}*(!%)^(_! | 0x11 %$}[!\#'^&_]{|" |    |
|    | 0x06 $%&'()*+/:;<_@) | 0x12 \SWORE|%'_!}\^" |    |
|    | 0x07 "/')=*%!&>#<:$+ | 0x13 ^{['&$|!_]%\"#} |    |
|    | 0x08 ;'*$&"(<%!#)RAC | 0x14 ']!|^#[$"_\}&{% |    |
|    | 0x09 ES:($&';%#+"<*/ | 0x15 @)($!CARTS*!@$_ |    |
|    | 0x0A ;'*$&"(<%!#)/+: | 0x16 !#%${"'}&[]^|_\ |    |
|    | 0x0B |'_!}$\%["#^{&] | 0x17 ]"_#$&}^%[{|\'! |    |
|    | 0x0C #{!"^&\]'|}_[PI | 0x18 _![&#{$%\^'|}"] |    | # Notice how PITYS wrapped.
|    |_____________________________________________|    |
|                                                       |
\_______________________________________________________/ 
       \_______________________________________/
```

If `n = 2` on the same example:

```
  _____________________________________________________
 /                                                     \ 
|     _____________________________________________     |
|    |                                             |    |
|    | Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   |    |
|    | Password Required                           |    |
|    | Attempts Remaining: X X                     |    | # N = 2 drives these X's.
|    |                                             |    |
|    | 0x01 $?_/%$ENACT||"} | 0x0D TYS"_'$\#|^%&{} |    |
|    | 0x02 }:!*@{/_<"[]#>; | 0x0E #{!"^&\]'|}_[$% |    |
|    | 0x03 $%&'()*+/:;<\_' | 0x0F }|[(%SMELL/_$@( |    |
|    | 0x04 ^SMART(!@$*'^_@ | 0x10 []_#!"{|}'%$\&^ |    |
|    | 0x05 (*@#%}*(!%)^(_! | 0x11 %$}[!\#'^&_]{|" |    |
|    | 0x06 $%&'()*+/:;<_@) | 0x12 \SWORE|%'_!}\^" |    |
|    | 0x07 "/')=*%!&>#<:$+ | 0x13 ^{['&$|!_]%\"#} |    |
|    | 0x08 ;'*$&"(<%!#)RAC | 0x14 ']!|^#[$"_\}&{% |    |
|    | 0x09 ES:($&';%#+"<*/ | 0x15 @)($!CARTS*!@$_ |    |
|    | 0x0A ;'*$&"(<%!#)/+: | 0x16 !#%${"'}&[]^|_\ |    |
|    | 0x0B |'_!}$\%["#^{&] | 0x17 ]"_#$&}^%[{|\'! |    |
|    | 0x0C #{!"^&\]'|}_[PI | 0x18 _![&#{$%\^'|}"] |    | # Notice how PITYS wrapped.
|    |_____________________________________________|    |
|                                                       |
\_______________________________________________________/ 
       \_______________________________________/
```

*These examples were manually crafted, so the distribution is not randomized, sorry.*

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count will be the accepted winner. I will bounty this after 3 days if no answers have been submitted for a total of 250 REP.

Comment: Quick!  No one answer for 3 days!  (kidding). This is my new favorite ascii-art challenge.

Comment: @nmjcman101 what was your last favorite?

Comment: What does the `NAMES` in the 2nd bullet point mean? "*All passwords can be expected to be of equal length, though this doesn't matter.*" or  "*All passwords in l **must** be of equal length.*"? It may just be me being blind (again!) but I don't see `RACES` in either output - should we take this to mean that there should be a possibility of a password not being used? Is `Math.random` (and equivalents) sufficiently random for the purposes of this challenge?

Comment: Do there have to be non-alphanumeric spacers between two passwords or is it fine if they generate right next to each other (non-overlapping)?

Comment: @nmjcman101 Sorry :P but not sorry :P

Comment: Do the passwords need to have the possibility of wrapping right-around from 0x18 to 0x01?

Comment: Can there can be extra spaces at the end of the lines?

Comment: @JonathanAllan all passwords can wrap, but no, that's not possible. They must wrap sequentially from lower byte-address to a higher one.

Comment: @dzaima outside of the terminal, yes, inside, no.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino there must be junk inbetween words.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES8), <s>575</s> <s>568</s> 564 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

Takes input in currying syntax `(r)(a)`, where ***r*** is the number of remaining attempts and ***a*** is the array of passwords.

```
r=>a=>[...C=`!"#[]^$%&'*+;<{}=`].reduce((s,c)=>(x=s.split(c)).join(x.pop()),`  "%%__
 /;;# \\ 
[ "} $Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink'!Password Required#}'!Attempts Remaining:${" X".repeat(r).padEnd(9)};[$^1=^D<2=^E<3=^F<4*0<5*1<6*2<7*3<8*4<9*5<A*6<B*7<C*8='+"[|
|;;#'|
\\"{_/ 
}'\\&%/= ]]]]] | }' {%%%<='+ ^#}}}+|
[|*=0x1'   "{{{%___$+;#}} !^0x0]ZZZ[|}#;}"&{![+ `).replace(/Z/g,(c,i)=>a.join``[(i%58>>5?y++:x++)%L],x=(R=n=>Math.random()*n|0)(L=360),y=x+180,[...Array(L-(n=a.sort(_=>R(3)-1).length)*a[0].length)].map(_=>a[R(n)]+=(C+`>?@()/:\\_|`)[R(27)]))
```

*<sup>Syntax highlighter disabled on purpose. It has no clue what to do with that.</sup>*

#### Demo

```js
let f =

r=>a=>[...C=`!"#[]^$%&'*+;<{}=`].reduce((s,c)=>(x=s.split(c)).join(x.pop()),`  "%%__
 /;;# \\ 
[ "} $Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink'!Password Required#}'!Attempts Remaining:${" X".repeat(r).padEnd(9)};[$^1=^D<2=^E<3=^F<4*0<5*1<6*2<7*3<8*4<9*5<A*6<B*7<C*8='+"[|
|;;#'|
\\"{_/ 
}'\\&%/= ]]]]] | }' {%%%<='+ ^#}}}+|
[|*=0x1'   "{{{%___$+;#}} !^0x0]ZZZ[|}#;}"&{![+ `).replace(/Z/g,(c,i)=>a.join``[(i%58>>5?y++:x++)%L],x=(R=n=>Math.random()*n|0)(L=360),y=x+180,[...Array(L-(n=a.sort(_=>R(3)-1).length)*a[0].length)].map(_=>a[R(n)]+=(C+`>?@()/:\\_|`)[R(27)]))

O.innerText = f(3)(["SMART","ENACT","SWORE","PITYS","SMELL","CARTS","RACES"])
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

Comment: Could you save anything using ES8 to populate the attempts like so: `Attempts Remaining:${" X".repeat(r).padEnd(8)}`?

Comment: @Shaggy That does save 3 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: `Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink'!Password Required#}'!Attempts Remaining:` oof... I should've paraphrased to save non-golfing langs bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 585 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(l,n,r=range):
	u,c='_ ';a=[choice('!"#$%&\'()*+/:;<=>?@[\\]^_{|}')for i in c*360];L=len(l[0]);i={*r(360-len(l[0]))};p=lambda x:'0x%02X'%x+c+''.join(a[15*x:][:15])
	for q in l:s=choice([*i]);a[s:s+L]=q;i-={*r(s+~L,s+-~-~L)}
	return'''  %s
 /%s\\
|# %s #|
?%s?
? Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   ?
? Password Required   ######?
? Attempts Remaining:%-25s?
?%s?
%%s?%s?
|%s|
\%s/
#   \%s/'''.replace('?','|#|').replace('#',c*4)%(u*53,c*53,u*45,c*45,' X'*n,c*45,u*45,c*55,u*55,u*39)%('|    | %s | %s |    |\n'*12)%sum([(p(x),p(x+12))for x in r(12)],())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVLRbpswFH0uX3EXxmwDadKmTBqMZVmUh0p0qZJI7QSsYsRp3YEhNmhMpfn1zs6qjYdz7jnX18cY6t/NQ8UnLy87UZUgMr5VxMq6Eo1tbOkOdrhwuStC1bqnxDdOWjcP0R2gIAvj/KFiOcXozcB8a71LECa2M/KDj@Gn6ec4SdLvd0/9MyK7SgADxiG3J@/HaRCFBeW4iMcpCVj4ZAus7OE/jzwHdVhk5Y9tBp2Pxp01Pr9FVufkDkKnjxXjOIvPPLvz09g/81JinOiEvU4ofBm@niq2mdo/i6UvnSgN9wEbHrOkc4hc6QwPw0NEno0TQZtWcIQQgCUNGFkySYzeVALM3phacmpM4YYWeVVSaCpYLb/Ml3DJt61sBKMS8OaKwIaKsmD8JwDo9deZlL8qsYUV3bdM0K3yzeOju7OmoWXdSNUtM8YZv/et4bmnk3ScpUBzb8neSCw5Mkw1rgt1ylNB6yLTtz5FLurNHpH/lonc3L4gFm5tb6JKBa194WnTcxHcIpv/rV9dT1dHmHxQU6hXOdDrV38FLROO7LNzYsm2xDGucUdcBY6yjl@20/cusJKpiwl5qQXjDVb/DYQQD9ZXs9Vm4A4WX2dzzeub5Wqh@Ppy822t9dUiihTP1TKtV7P5Yj1IXeBq/EJt9wc)

-70 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan
-9 bytes thanks to myself (finally!)
-72 bytes thanks to notjagan

Comment: [Another 35 bytes off!](http://bit.ly/2hMSkmK)

Comment: And [15 more.](http://bit.ly/2hMmd6Y)

Comment: [16 more removed!](http://bit.ly/2uI78EM) (there has to be better way to do this than a bunch of comments)

Comment: Another [6 bytes off](http://bit.ly/2urpvhF) by half-reverting one of my other changes (I really should stop commenting).

Comment: @notjagan I don't mind comments :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>588</s> 560 + 1 (-a) = <s>589</s> 561 bytes

*Cut 28 bytes with the suggestions Dom pointed out*

```perl
$,=$/;$_=" X"x pop@F;say"  "."_"x53," /".$"x53 ."\\",$q="|     ".'_'x45 ."     |",$e=($b="|    |").$"x45 .$b,"$b Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   $b
$b Password Required".$"x27 .$b,"$b Attempts Remaining:$_".$"x(25-length).$b,$e;map{$s.=(grep/[^\w,.`-]|_/,map{chr}33..125)[rand 27]}1..360;($t=substr$s,$r=rand 360-($l=length),$l,$_)=~/[a-z]/i&&(substr$s,$r,$l,$t)&&push@F,$_ while$_=pop@F;@o=$s=~/.{15}/g;printf"$b 0x0%X %s | 0x%02X %s $b\n",$_,$o[$_-1],$_+12,$o[$_+11]for 1..12;say$b.'_'x45 .$b,$q=~y/_/ /r,$q=" \\"."_"x54 ."/",$"x6 .$q=~s/_{15}//r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFhb9owEP2@X3GyDpqoiZ0E0kpDlsoQlSqVURGkdgKWJcWFaCEJdhB0hf70ZU6oqvnTO733znf3CiFTv6rQ4sh6GHICT@QARV7c3PZU9EoACCUhOfgdiwAjFGsIlMznxMItJ0eoH6EX4cWh62uiqY@aFNzA@ENwJGbtrAUYWwRjeBTpc74RUOYwGX8bjOEuW@5UKROhwJiOTJgKuUmT7Ld2Y/xFOx4ipfa5XMJEbHeJFMtmGO/6s2W/LMWmKJUWbKIkS7LVVwwbkeH5diqyVbk2azGK3iYq3lBRbqykKNjs53xv0V/24hgyq6ae1/LU6VDqer45k1G2BO96cXIp7Vw5PQNLrnaxHhaVhZI3vCZsA1P@8Y2FqYWhyd/ZLLL/LFjSbhv/eRq6NNvtYqfWN7daCvt1kgodwPn0NzlHpd30zfVPbNUrZJKVL/WWzsFpPUFLwVHDluM1GON5pk8eWpjPMLTdhcaXrncuL1138ZJLcOt96lAx/oyrvsaWv7@ykAGTTaKgoz1H3tVxMt2WHK60UssUC5t5mKyqYNSfTGH4vT@YQvA4ngzh4W76I4BgNLy/h4EmA5j0B8MAun/zokzyTFX2yKeO61R29A8)

*Previously:*

```perl
$,=$/;$_=" X"x pop@F;say"  "."_"x53," /".($"x53)."\\",$q="|     ".('_'x45)."     |",$e=($b="|    |").($"x45).$b,"$b Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   $b
$b Password Required".($"x27).$b,"$b Attempts Remaining:$_".($"x(25-length)).$b,$e;$s=join'',map{(split//,'!"#$%&\'()*+/:;<=>?@[]^_{|}\\')[int rand 27]}1..360;while($_=pop@F){if(($t=substr$s,$r=rand 360-($l=length),$l,$_)=~/[a-z]/i){substr$s,$r,$l,$t;push@F,$_}}@o=$s=~/.{15}/g;printf"$b 0x0%X %s | 0x%02X %s $b\n",$_,$o[$_-1],$_+12,$o[$_+11]for 1..12;say$b.('_'x45).$b,$q=~y/_/ /r,$q=" \\".("_"x54)."/",($"x6).$q=~s/_{15}//r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJtb5swGPy@X/HMcwYsgIGGVirzlixKpUrNUoVI7RQyBIuTuCNAMFHT5eWnjxlSbePT4buz7nnOOSsSt6qwTjHxcEgRPKId5FnevfFE9IIAkIlCtHMvdAQEmSqusWaiIEA63lB0gPqThBIqu44rmebgIFlGVRy/Kg5Ia7y1Asc6wjE8sORHtmZQZjAefemP4Dadb0VZcCZAnQw1mLBinfD0p7Tj@I103EdCPGfFHMZss@UFm5/zOFd/7@yVJVvnpZCKdcRTni6vcXhWqY5rJCxdliutkWPmYUGfMp4qir6O8r0q8oSXhOjKW/QOt94Hiqp9aJNr7yP99Lk7nX0P94djECjalKclFFE6B@dqdrRN8@LS8p5XPGGq3GCzO23PF6qKSyq2sRwJCx0XtLFIraHihL5G0XGi41CjJzKNjF8zwrX9f5aGLb18K1bdG6k7HrsZlalPxNzb7pEsvbyQYRb16NbOaj1CS8BBwpblNBjHQSqbCHWcTXFo2DOJ27Zz/m3b9myRFSAnsJ26bRz/q7He0IaeXkhIgBRN1SA7N9XmNXRkzwTp9V4vpVYKBQmbSKSoKn/YG09g8LXXn4D/MBoP4P528s0Hfzi4u4O@JH0Y9/oDHzq/s7zkWSoqY@ialm1VRvQH)

Input is on one line, space separated: first the strings, then the number

**How?**

```perl
$,=$/;          # delimiter between fields is newline
$_=" X"x pop@F; # set number of attempts left
say             # output the header
"  "."_"x53,
" /".($"x53)."\\",
$q="|     ".('_'x45)."     |",
$e=($b="|    |").($"x45).$b,
"$b Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink   $b
$b Password Required".($"x27).$b,
"$b Attempts Remaining:$_".($"x(25-length)).$b,
$e;
$s=join'',map{(split//,'!"#$%&\'()*+/:;<=>?@[]^_{|}\\')[int rand 27]}1..360; # create random string long enough for entire screen
while($_=pop@F){  # for each given string
if(($t=substr$s,$r=rand 360-($l=length),$l,$_) # attempt to insert it
=~/[a-z]/i)                                    # but check if it overlaps another string
{substr$s,$r,$l,$t;                            # if it does, take it out
push@F,$_}}                                    # and put it back in line
@o=$s=~/.{15}/g;                               # split "memory dump" into chunks
printf"$b 0x0%X %s | 0x%02X %s $b\n",$_,$o[$_-1],$_+12,$o[$_+11]for 1..12; #output the grid
say                                            # output the footer
$b.('_'x45).$b,$q=~y/_/ /r,
$q=" \\".("_"x54)."/",
($"x6).$q=~s/_{15}//r
```

Comment: Nice answer to a complex problem! You should be able to save almost 30 bytes by removing the brackets around the repetition operator, you can add a space so the `.` isn't used as a decimal point. Also to get the punctuation you can use something like ``(grep/[^\w,.`-]|_/,map{chr}33..125)`` and you don't need to call `int` on an array index! Changing the `while` loop to postfix and using `&&` instead of `if` should save a few too. When you're building `$s`, if you have `$s.=` inside the map instead of using `join` drops a few more. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 225 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
R“EC"+w╗─║Z⁰2BΥø‘▓"▲╔⁸‘'²∙+"⅟Δλ≤LK⅟ΗΠ.JN║«⁸⅟‘▓+╬⁷"№D↓tι▲‛Q─Ρδν∙υ4Ρψ▲¦‽↑√Ε┐Ζ5↔‛⅟≤š▼¦⁾○ΔΡ%³‘ū91 tž85ž.ΖX Ο'⁹7žø]Xe@*c{leκψI1ž}_:@øŗ⁄c∑⁄≠}l{"T-)⅞↑°Χpjζ⅓īa0ε+Μ‛⁶ρ\=↔⅟¹‘ψ}¹K@Gŗ'¹nο²²Z+8«m«ο+I{@∑"0x0”Κ}¹6«n_'⁷1ž'⁵16«┐∙ž'⁸4 19∙ž89╬5
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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_,inputs=JTVCJTIyU01BUlQlMjIlMkMlMjJFTkFDVCUyMiUyQyUyMlNXT1JFJTIyJTJDJTIyUElUWVMlMjIlMkMlMjJTTUVMTCUyMiUyQyUyMkNBUlRTJTIyJTJDJTIyUkFDRVMlMjIlNUQlMEE0)
Expects array input on the stack and the number input an an input, so `→"` is added in the online program for ease-of-use.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES8), 639 bytes

```js
(w,n,r=i=>Math.random()*i|0,s=b=>{for(i=b[k];i;i--)[b[i-1],b[j]]=[b[j=r(i)],b[i-1]]},a=Array(360-w[k="length"]*--w[0][k]),m=[...a].map((j,i)=>~(j=d.slice(0,w[k]).indexOf(i))?w[j]:`!"#$%&'()*+/:;<=>?@[\\]^_{|}`[r(27)],s(w),s(d=[...a.keys()])).join``.match(/.{15}/g).map((v,i)=>"0x"+(i+1).toString(16).padStart(2,0)+" "+v))=>`  _53
 / 53\\
| 5_45 5|
${["","Welcome to ROBCO Industries (TM) Termlink","Password Required","Attempts Remaining:"+" X".repeat(n),"",...m.slice(0,12).map((x,i)=>x+" | "+m[i+12])].map(x=>"| 4| "+x.padEnd(43)+" | 4|").join`
`}
| 4|_45| 4|
| 55|
\\_55/
 7\\_39/`.replace(/[_ ]([1-9]+)/g,(m,n)=>m[0].repeat(n))
```

The hex labels are in lowercase; if uppercase was required, that would be an additional 14 bytes for `.toUpperCase()`.

### Test Snippet

Better viewed over on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/justinm53/pen/EvgWPP).

Comment: You can save a byte by currying the 2 parameters and moving your variables into the first `repeat`.